# What would be the next number in the following sequence of numbers? 9,15,21

Tags: number-sequence

9-15-21-25-27-33-35-39-45-49-51-55-57-63-65-69-75-77-81-85-87-91-93-95-99-?-?-?-?-?

What are the next five numbers in this sequence?

Hint 1: This sequence can go on indefinitely

Hint 2: Based upon another sequence.

Comment: Please see [Number Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Comment: OEIS has this sequence.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil In what way did my original question differ from your model question.

Comment: @GwenKillerby: It's not supposed to be a model, but a bad example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is

> 105

and the sequence is

> Odd nonprimes

Comment: Did I make the sequence too long?

Comment: @GwenKillerby Pretty much any bare OEIS sequence is a bad puzzle; such puzzles are uninteresting and, in many cases, are less an exercise in "deduce the pattern" and more one of "guess what sequence the poser was thinking of".  Beastly Gerbil already pointed you at **[the post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do)** which mentions why these tend to make bad puzzles; maybe you should read it instead of challenging the helpful critique.